# Django string disappears in template when applying unicode filter

Tags: python, django, templates, unicode

I have a self-written tool with is converting indian transliterated strings into unicode output, working like this:

```
>>> x_HK_to_UNI("ahaM")
```

Wich results in the following string:

```
'aha\xe1\xb9\x82''
```

So far so good, this tool is tested and has been used on converting thousand of documents. 
Now i am writing a Django app and wish to apply this function as a filter in a template. The code looks like this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django import template
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from xliterator import *
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def process_trans_for_html(string):
    newstring = []
    string = string.split(' ')
    for word in string:
        if word[-3:] == '_xn' :
            newstring.append(x_HK_to_UNI(word[:1]).upper()+(x_HK_to_UNI(word[1:-3]).lower())
        elif word[-3:] == '_xh' :
            newstring.append(x_HK_to_UNI(word[:-3]).lower())
        else:
            newstring.append(word)
    return ' '.join(newstring)
```

In the template I pass data to the filter this way:

```
{{ line.line|process_trans_for_html }}
```

Basically the function is working as long as nothing is replaced, so when it processes *yena_xn* it is displayed on the website correctly as *Yena*.
But *ahaM_xn* should be turned into *ahaṃ* (this is the job of `x_HK_to_UNI`) - and when such a word is encountered, the whole string just disappears and leaves blank space on the page.

Any suggestion on this? I tried already all kinds of unicode transformation stuff and there seems to be no much help. I feel rather confused. There is also no error message.

I use Python2.7.

EDIT: Here the relevant parts of xliterator.py:

```
import sys, re, os

SEPARATOR_PRIMARY=";"

class Xlator(dict): # Xlator is initialized through a mapping
    def _make_regex(self):
        """Build re object based on the keys of the current dict"""
        return re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, self.keys())))
    def __call__(self, match):
        """Handler invoked for each regex match"""
        return self[match.group(0)] 
    def xlate(self, text):
        """Translate text, returns the modified text"""
        return self._make_regex().sub(self, text)

def _transposeDict(d): # returns a dict with key value transposed
    nd = {}
    for (k,v) in d.items():
        nd[v]=k
    return nd

#Unicode to HK  
DICT_UNI_HK = {'ā':'A','Ā':'A','ī':'I','Ī':'I','ū':'U','Ū':'U',\
    'ṛ':'R','Ṛ':'R','ṝ':'RR','ḷ':'L','Ḷ':'L','ḹ':'LL',\
    'ṃ':'M','Ṃ':'M','ḥ':'H','Ḥ':'H','ṅ':'G','Ṅ':'G',\
    'ñ':'J','Ñ':'J','ṭ':'T','Ṭ':'T','ḍ':'D','Ḍ':'D',\
    'ṇ':'N','Ṇ':'N','ś':'z','Ś':'z','ṣ':'S','Ṣ':'S',
    } 

def x_UNI_to_HK(in_str_UNI): # input: 
    xlator_Obj = Xlator(DICT_UNI_HK)
    return xlator_Obj.xlate(in_str_UNI) 

def x_HK_to_UNI(in_str_UNI):
    DICT_HK_UNI = dict (zip(DICT_UNI_HK.values(),DICT_UNI_HK.keys()))
    xlator_Obj = Xlator(DICT_HK_UNI)
    return xlator_Obj.xlate(in_str_UNI)
```

Comment: Have you debugged in the process_trans_for_html method? If not how about it. If you haven't set up django debugging yet, how about sprinkling some log messages to see what's happening inside that. Since your *x_HK_to_UNI* is a blackbox for stackoverflow reading, answering this question involves a lot of guesswork. Unrelated from xliterator import * is something you want to

Comment: I just added the code for the xliterator, sorry I forgot to do so. :)

Comment: I could solve it, a simple reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8') in the header of the xliterator.py did it. But now the whole process is slow as hell, takes years to load the page... But basicly it is working. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself,
the following was missing in xliterator.py
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

Very basic problem I guess. :) Now the process it slow as hell and it takes ages to load the page, but basicly it is doing what it should do.

Comment: You can accept your own answer. Sorry couldn't help. As for speed you can probably  speed things up a bit by changing your make_regex() method to not compile the regex each and every time. And you are also transposing your dictionary each and every time. Why not generate the transpose once and save it?

Comment: That means you've got an implicit str->Unicode conversion in your code somewhere. `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` is a nasty hack to work around bad code

Answer (score 1):

Despite your main code having `from __future__ import unicode_literals` your xliterator.py script will be interpreted using Python 2.x syntax.

You've found that setting the default encoding to UTF-8 fixed your problem, which means Python has struggled to compare against and convert the UTF-8 encoded in xliterator.py. Django will have probably given you Unicode strings but you haven't told Python how to convert between (byte) strings and Unicode strings.

The easiest way to resolve this is to add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` to xliterator.py so that all the strings become Unicode strings.

Also add `# coding: utf-8` to the top of xliterator.py would ensure that your UTF-8 source code is correctly decoded to Unicode strings.

Comment: Thank you for the further explanation, that makes sense to me. :)